# How do I show a MapView or GoogleMap in a DialogFragment?

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a dialog created as a dialogFragment that has it's own XML layout. Is it possible to embed a map inside the DialogFragment with a reference to it, so I can update it's location?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.andrew.neighborlabour.CreateJobDialog">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
            android:text="Create Job"
            android:textAppearance="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textSize="24dp"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:lines="2"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </TextView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:hint="Address"
                android:id="@+id/etAddress"/>

            <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:id="@+id/map"
                tools:context=".MapsActivity"
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Create Job"
        android:id="@+id/btCreate"
        android:onClick="Create"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

into the XML I can see the map but i'm unsure how to interact with it from my java code.

dialogFragment:

```
public class CreateJobDialog extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_create_job, container, false);
        return view;
    }
}
```

to create the dialog:

```
CreateJobDialog createJobDialog = new CreateJobDialog();
                createJobDialog.show(this.getFragmentManager(), "NoticeDialogFragment");
```

Comment: Show your DialogFragment code....

Comment: @DanielNugent sure thing

Comment: Is the map the only thing in the xml layout?

Comment: @DanielNugent I added it, sorry was trying to keep the question general

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is pretty standard, just use the `getMapAsync()` method to get a reference to the Google Map.

The only surprising thing was that I had to use `getFragmentManager()` instead of `getChildFragmentManager()` inside of the DialogFragment code.  Normally when nesting a SupportMapFragment inside of a Fragment, you need to use the child FragmentManager, but apparently it's different for a DialogFragment.

Here's the DialogFragment code:

```
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;


public class MapDialogFragment extends DialogFragment
        implements OnMapReadyCallback{

    GoogleMap mMap;

    public MapDialogFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map_dialog, container, false);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(37.7688472,-122.4130859);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,11));

        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(latLng);
        markerOptions.title("Current Position");
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
        mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
    }
}
```

Launching the DialogFragment:

```
new MapDialogFragment().show(getSupportFragmentManager(), null);
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Ya I gave this method a try and the issue was in the `SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
` . The IDE said it couldn't cast a `Fragment` into a `SupportMapFragment`

Comment: specifically `inconvertible types; cannot cast 'android.app.Fragment' to 'com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment`

Comment: Hey thanks. I wasn't using `import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;` but `import android.app.DialogFragment;` made the difference

Answer (score 7):

I would add to the answer of @Daniel Nugent the implementation of the following code in the method `onDestroyView()`.

```
 @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        assert getFragmentManager() != null;
        Fragment fragment = (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
        FragmentTransaction ft = Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.remove(fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }
```

I followed the steps of his answer but was marking a 'FATAL EXCEPTION'.
When opening> close> back open 'DialogFragment'.

```
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #44: Error inflating class fragment
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #44: Duplicate id 0x7f0900c3, tag null, or parent id 0x7f090067 with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.
```

Note: it could be useful for someone else with the same problem as me to follow this answer.
I do not put my observation in comment, because I do not comply with the 50 reputation points.

Answer (score 1):

Well, i got some several issue due to multimap with google api. So i think a complete answer for a full reusable dialog use should be something like this (base on a previous answer).

```
public class MapDialogFragment extends DialogFragment
        implements OnMapReadyCallback{

    GoogleMap mMap;

    public MapDialogFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map_edit_location, container, false);


        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag("mapFragment");
        if (mapFragment == null) {
            mapFragment = new SupportMapFragment();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.add(R.id.mapFragmentContainer, mapFragment, "mapFragment");
            ft.commit();
            fm.executePendingTransactions();
        }
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(37.7688472,-122.4130859);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,11));

        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(latLng);
        markerOptions.title("Current Position");
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
        mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
    }


}
```

Then the xml file with google map (note that we use only the parent layout to avoid inflating a fragment inside another).

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mapFragmentContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

</LinearLayout>
```

The call from my fragment.

```
new MapDialogFragment().show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), null);
```

Hope it will help some people searching a dialog working EVEN in multimap context.